# How to find un used .h , .m and xibs from iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode

Please let me know if there is a way to find out un used .h , .m files and xibs from iOS application .thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally search has finished,great work by arun to find un used images as well as other files from application folder .

Still my question is pending,i need to get the un used files from project folder in xcode. If there is a way it would be appreciated

https://github.com/arun80/xcodeutils